# VC++ Default binding error?

Tags: api, ubuntu, visual-c++, vhdl

I am building a dll using VC++ that builds fine with no errors to include in my API.

The files are the result of a VHDL project that was converted to C++ using Freehdl in order for the logic to be used in multiple projects.

Only problem is that during testing, it shows the following...

[image: This is the console output using command line.]

I thought the problem was the memory size required by the functions being too large and so I reduced it to about 24 bits but the issue still persisted as shown...

[image]

I have not previously encountered this issue.
If anyone knows what could be the problem, please illuminate us.
Thanks.

Comment: Googling this error message shows that it might originate in a VHDL simulator, is that the case here? If yes, you should go a bit more into detail regarding the simulator you are using. It also also not clear what you mean by "functions too large" and "reduced to 24 bits", is this about VHDL functions then?

Comment: Actually it is. Good instincts. I coded an IC in VHDL and converted it to C++ using freehdl. I then migrated the files and dependencies to windows and built a dll because I found the logic could have multiple applications. As far as memory use is concerned, I cannot enter into detail only to say that it has been addressed *sorry*. Now I'm wondering how to resolve this.

Comment: So this is a problem with freehdl, not c++. It's probably unlikely that you get an answer here, maybe the freehdl mailing list would be better suited. But you could try to tag this question with vhdl though, that could increase the chances.

Comment: You need to  figure out how to compile the entities you want to bind to those components in FreeHDL, and how to link all the resulting bits of C++ together.

Answer (score 0):

*Default binding* in normal VHDL compilation means that all the VHDL components are hooked up with entities, without using a configuration file to specify the hook-up. When this fails, there is likely have a mismatch between component declarations and entities.

I have not used FreeHDL and can't comment on what happened here precisely, but I read that "Each VHDL entity declaration is transformed into a C++ class.", which may mean that either the original VHDL is broken or incomplete, or that it didn't get interpreted correctly. Apparently, it checks some of this only at run time.

A good place to start will be to actually compile your VHDL project with another simulator - this will tell you if that is at fault. Otherwise you may have hit a FreeHDL bug.

Comment: Yup. I decided to go with Verilator instead and the C++ codes have no bugs. So it's definitely a Freehdl bug.